# Google Ad Manager API Report Querying

Tags: python, api, google-ad-manager, google-ads-api

Google has the following docs for the ad manager [here](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/pqlreference#python). Unfortunately their example:

```
# Set the start and end dates of the report to run (past 8 days).
end_date = date.today()
start_date = end_date - timedelta(days=8)

# Create report job.
report_job = {
    'reportQuery': {
        'dimensions': ['LINE_ITEM_ID', 'LINE_ITEM_NAME'],
        'columns': ['AD_SERVER_IMPRESSIONS', 'AD_SERVER_CLICKS',
                    'AD_SERVER_CTR', 'AD_SERVER_CPM_AND_CPC_REVENUE',
                    'AD_SERVER_WITHOUT_CPD_AVERAGE_ECPM'],
        'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
        'startDate': start_date,
        'endDate': end_date
    }
}

# Initialize a DataDownloader.
report_downloader = client.GetDataDownloader(version='v202008')

try:
  # Run the report and wait for it to finish.
  report_job_id = report_downloader.WaitForReport(report_job)
except errors.AdManagerReportError as e:
  print('Failed to generate report. Error was: %s' % e)

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(
    suffix='.csv.gz', mode='wb', delete=False) as report_file:
  # Download report data.
  report_downloader.DownloadReportToFile(
      report_job_id, 'CSV_DUMP', report_file)
```

yields a `KeyError: 'date'` on the `report_job_id` line. My authorization is correct and I can make other calls with my client. My question is, how does one need to update `report_job` in order for the example to work. I tried changing `'dateRangeType'` however [this](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/api/reference/v202008/ReportService.ReportQuery#startDate) states it must be 'CUSTOM_DATE'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the example is wrong and the proper syntax for the example is:

```py
'startDate': {
    'year': 2021,
    'month': 3,
    'day': 1
},
```

https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/issues/475#issuecomment-821209008